# Edit column entries in data frame using json.loads()

Tags: python, json, dataframe

given is a data frame which has column 'A' where each entry is one dictionary. The data frame looks like this:

```
                        A     B
0  {'z': 5, 'g': 3, 'd': 1}   a
1  {'j': 7, 'd': 1}           b
2  {'k': 1, 'd': 6}           c
3  {'n': 1, 'q': 1}           d
```

These dictionaries are now supposed to be replaced with the sum of the integers they contain. This should be done using the *.apply* function as well as the *json.loads()* function. The result should therefore look like this:

```
   A     B
0  9     a
1  8     b
2  7     c
3  2     d
```

However, I am not sure how to apply *json.loads()* in this context.

Comment: Do you understand what `json.loads` does generally? Do you understand why it would be useful here? Can you write a function that takes in, say, `"{'z': 5, 'g': 3, 'd': 1}"` and returns `9`?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, json.loads converts a json object to a python dictionary, which is useful in this case to use sum(d.values()) on the corresponding dictionary (where d is the converted dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` is created in the following way -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [{'z': 5, 'g': 3, 'd': 1}, {'j': 7, 'd': 1}], "B": ['a', 'b']})
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: sum(x.values()))
```

If it was created in the following way -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [json.dumps({'z': 5, 'g': 3, 'd': 1}), json.dumps({'j': 7, 'd': 1})], "B": ['a', 'b']})
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: sum(json.loads(x).values()))
```

**Update**
Third option per the comments -

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["\"{'z': 5, 'g': 3, 'd': 1}\"", "\"{'z': 5, 'g': 3, 'd': 5}\""], "B": ['a', 'b']})
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: sum(ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(x)).values()))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am not sure how it was created but the second solution returns an error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1). It seems like the dictionaries are not meant to be used in a json format. However, the task explicitly states that json.loads() should be used. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Try using doing `import ast` and then `df['A'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`. If that results a dictionary you can continue from there

Comment: "the second solution returns an error" This is because the text in your DataFrame is not actually properly in JSON format. "the task explicitly states" what task?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel. Is this comment for me? I just run the second example and the code works as I expect, no errro

Comment: That was my fault. The dictionaries in the data frame are actually in double quotes. So like this: "{'z': 5, 'g': 3, 'd': 1}" . Does this make a difference?

Comment: Please see my last update, if you add  a real example we can help you solve it quicker